# Do I have to await an async function in useEffect that is already async?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have the following code below, and I call my function `usersaApi.getUsersId` it in a `useEffect` function, do I have to make the response (as it returns the values, not the Promise) an async function?

```
const usersApi = {
  getUserIds: async storyId => {
    const result = await axios
      .get(`${users + userId}.json`)
      .then(({ data }) => data);

    return result;
  },
}

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await usersApi.getUserIds().then(data => setUserIds(data));
    };

    fetchData();
}, []);
```

What's the difference also between using:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    await usersApi.getUserIds().then(data => setUserIds(data));
};
```

vs.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
     const result = await usersApi.getUserIds().then(data => setUserIds(data));

     return result;
};
```

I presume I can just await the response and not return the result right? It's kind of two questions here:

1) Do I have to use async/await on a function that is already async/await
2) The difference between using await & return on a function that already returns data, not promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Do I have to use async/await on a function that is already async/await

It's up to you what syntax you want to use. You could either use async/await, or you could use the older `.then` style. Personally i find the async await style easier to understand so i personally prefer it. I would however recommend **against** mixing the two syntaxes. It's almost never necessary to do so, and it just ends up making the code harder to understand. Either write:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const data = await userApi.getUserIds();
  setUserIds(data);
}
```

or:

```
const fetchData = () => {
  userApi.getUserIds.then(data => setUserIds(data));
}
```

> 2) The difference between using await & return on a function that already returns data, not promises.

Async/await exists to simplify the syntax for working with promises. If you aren't using promises, you don't need async/await.

Comment: This didn't really answer my question, I guess what I'm trying to get at is do I have to `await` the `userApi.getUserIds()` inside the `useEffect` even though I've already made the function itself async? Because if not I could just use the `useEffect` and do `usersApi.getUserIds().then(data => setUserIds(data));` could I not?

Comment: No, you do not need to stick an await in addition to doing a .then. Do one or the other, not both.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, this is what I was looking for: If you aren't using promises, you don't need async/await. Seeing as though the `getUsersIds` returns data and not a promise, there's no need for async in my useEffect, can you confirm this?

Comment: `Seeing as though the getUsersIds returns data and not a promise` That's incorrect. getUsersIds returns a promise. **All** `async` functions return promises. `async` functions make the syntax for promises easier, they do not eliminate the fact that promises are involved. Since getUsersIds returns a promise, you either need to call `.then` on that promise, or you need to use `async`/`await` on that promise. (and as i said, i strongly encourage you to pick just one style and not mix them -- I only mention both for completeness).

Comment: Ahh I see what you're saying, the async function *always* returns a promise, so doing `userApi.getUserIds.then(data => setUserIds(data));` is the same but just a different style, and this will still be async because when it gets resolved, it ticks back onto the event loop and cleared, right?

Comment: getUserIds() returns a promise. If you call `.then(data => setUserIds(data))`, you're telling the promise what function you want to be called once that promise resolves. Or if you go with the async/await approach, then `const data = await ` and the rest of the function specifies what to run when the promise resolves. Some time later the http request completes, the promise resolves, and then your code gets put into the event loop and runs the next chance it gets. Either way, your code to call setUserIds will have to wait to run.

Comment: That's a great way to explain it Nicholas, thank you very much.